# How to build a paper-element app with dart?

Tags: model-view-controller, dart, material-design, paper-elements

I want to build a large application in Dart using material design. To accomplish this I included paper_elements into my project. My problem is, that I can't think of a good way to build my multi page application with paper_elements. Usually I create objects which would create their elements inline and add / remove themselves to the dom. The way I understand the paper_element tutorials I found so far this is not possible with them.

Is there a simple way to use paper_elements in dart while having an object based structure? For example I would have my application which loads either a register or login object and displays it in the browser. When logging in it should load a menu object which displays a menu and so on. All page changes should happen without a page reload.

I'm looking forward to all help, examples or links you could provide regarding my problem.

Cheers,
Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dart you normally build the app as SPA (single page application) without reload.
You can add remove a `paper-element` like normal DOM elements (div, input, ...) `querySelector('#placeholder').append(new Element.tag('paper-input'));`
You can also use `<template if="{{}}">` or `<template repeat="{{}}"`> to make Polymer auto-insert these elements when certain conditions are fulfilled or for each value in a collection.

Your question isn't very specific but I guess all you need is already available here on SO as Q/A. Just search for `[dart-polymer]`. If you don't find anything just ask and we point you in the right direction.

a few that might be relevant

- [Dart Language: Polymer - Working with views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665906)
- [How to update polymer element bindings after it was removed from DOM and inserted again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805350)
- [How to add attributes to a dynamically created component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928266)
- [how to implement a main function in polymer apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982489) (you don't need a `main()` when you use a polymer-element that acts as a container for your entire application)
- [Is imperative Mustache-Binding in Polymer.dart supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203830)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This sounds like a solution that will work for me. 
I've tried to implement this for my project but stumbled across a problem: the elements will be added correctly (i.e. <paper-input></paper-input> in my  initPolymer().run(() {Polymer.onReady.then((_){... method, but will not be rendered as paper elements in the dom.

The html file contains those includes:     <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">

Comment: You don't need the this import `<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">` in the entry page, only in the HTML files of your own Polymer elements. You need an import for each paper-element you want to use instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this solves my problem just fine! One last question though, I have a custom polymer-element named "register-card". It consists of a div element containing two paper-input elements. When I import my custom element it will be in the dom looking like this: <polymer-element name="register-card"><template>#document-fragment<style></style><div class="login-header" layout="" horizontal="" center="">[... paper-input 1 and 2 ...]</div><content></content></template></polymer-element> but the <register-card> element I added to the dom stays empty (without any shadow-node)

Comment: I'm missing a script tag in your `register-card` definition. You either need to add a `<script type='application/dart'>` (inline or a link to a *.dart file) that contains the associated class or the `noscript` attribute like `<polymer-elment name='register-card' noscript>`. If this doesn't solve your problem it might be better to create a new question. Discussing code in comments is horrible because of the missing formatting options and the limited size.